# Spark History Server data as CSV file download

Tags: user-interface, apache-spark

Is there any way to download Spark History Server UI data in CSV format ?

Thanks

Comment: Sure. Write a web scraper. What information do you want? What have you tried?

Comment: Initially I tried to read from HDFS as Spark History is stored there but UI information is more close to my requirement . Is there any example on Web Sracpper ? Also Spark History UI has 1K+ pages ...

Comment: No, I have no examples, and asking for one would be considered off topic for Stackoverflow. In order for this to be considered a programming question, you've not specified what language you would accomplished this in, and the question itself is not about writing Spark applications